# Goole Play Application update - Keep Getting SSL Error Handler

Tags: android, google-play

Google Play keeps rejecting my app updates with SSL Error Handler notifications. I tried every code example on how to implement 'onReceivedSslError'and even tried to remove it completely. all emails mention an older version number. Tried reaching out to support but no answer from them;
My latest attempt was:

```
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                               SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

    int primaryError = error.getPrimaryError();

    switch (primaryError)
    {
        case SSL_UNTRUSTED:
        case SSL_NOTYETVALID:
        case SSL_DATE_INVALID:
        case SSL_EXPIRED:
        case SSL_IDMISMATCH: {
            handler.cancel();
        }
        break;
    }
    SslCertificate serverCertificate = error.getCertificate();
    String certDomain = serverCertificate.getIssuedTo().getCName();
    try {
        if(certDomain.equals(new URL(error.getUrl()).getHost())) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
        else {
            handler.cancel();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        handler.cancel();
    }
}
```

Help please,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use this code where you have used you webview..

```
webview.loadUrl(url);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AboutUsActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.notification_error_ssl_cert_invalid);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            
                        }
                    });
                    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
```

Override onReceivedSslError at all webView component.
**@Override
public void onReceivedSslError**